# Videos will not play on android devices using MediaManager

Tags: codenameone

When displaying am mp4 video that was recorded on an android device, the video works on an iPhone, but on the android device the video was recorded on it displayed an error

[image: error]

And failed to play. Attempts to play other videos just didn't even render the video player

```
Media video = com.codename1.media.MediaManager.createMedia(url, true);
if (video != null) {
    video.setNativePlayerMode(true);
}
// place the video in the container
container.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, video.getVideoComponent());
```

If I open the video using Display.getInstance.execute(url), it plays fine on the android device and on the iPhone.

```
Display.getInstance().execute(url);
```

On iPhone the video(s) all seem to play correctly using the cn1 methods. In the simulator I am unable to playback anything.

I would like to keep this all in the cn1 app, I am creating a messaging app and want to get an experience like a standard chat/sms app.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
if (video != null) {
    video.setNativePlayerMode(true);
}
// place the video in the container
container.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, video.getVideoComponent());
```

But video can still be null in the invocation of `getVideoComponent()`. If the video media object is null this can be a result of a URL or mime type issue.

Comment: What is interesting is that this code works fine and the video plays on IOS, but not on android. As a developer, what can I do to ensure the same experience on both devices?

Comment: There are a lot of small nuances like that with things that rely on native peer behavior. Basically the URL you give us is passed to the lower level implementation which is OS native and out of our control. However, without further information it's hard for me to know what failed and what isn't portable